# Stripe: Are customers per company?

Tags: stripe-payments

Say Joe is a customer of XYZ LLC and they use Stripe to process payments.  Joe opens chooses to create an account, storing his CC number with Stripe.

Say he is also a company of AAA Inc who also uses Stripe.  Is there anyway for AAA Inc to get Joe's already existing account?

Assume that AAA Inc. and XYZ LLC do not share API keys.

It does not seem so as the API seems to consider per company, or at least per API Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, no. Stripe is not that kind of platform (at least not yet).

However, Stripe has a product called [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). Based on your question, I don't think it's what you'd want to use — but for the sake of completeness, it does allow [sharing customers between connected accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers).